# Is there a way to read a contact's details with a Chooser?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, contacts

What I'm trying to do is import people in my app from `Contacts`. The details I need is First/Last names and the contact's picture. I know that there isn't a chooser to retrieve those details and also know about the `Microsoft.Phone.UserData.Contacts` class and how I can retrieve the list using the `FilterKind` enum. But I want to choose a contact from the "CHOOSE A CONTACT" Page that loads when showing a Chooser like `EmailAddressChooserTask`.

Basically I'm asking for a confirmation on whether in order to accomplish this I have to write a `PhoneApplicationPage` similar to the `Contacts` `LongListSelector`, with the results from the `Contacts.SearchCompleted` event.

Maybe someone already did this and I can avoid the overhead of virtualization (loading all contacts and showing their pictures) and search functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find a complete tutorial (and source code) for WP7.1 in [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/eshaham/archive/2011/10/10/windows-phone-jump-list-contact-chooser-control.aspx) :

> In this post I will be sharing the source code of my contact chooser
>   control, a control I needed to create for my “My Assistant” app, a
>   reminder application. If you can’t wait to read the rest of the
>   explanation, you can scroll down and download the source code.

The author is doing exactly all the steps you are describing and using the same controls and API :

- `Microsoft.Phone.UserData.Contacts` API remains unchanged in WP8.0, so you won't have to change code pieces regarding contact retrieving.
- The author is using Windows Phone Toolkit to take advantage of the `LongListSelector` control that was not part of the WP7 API. But as it does now, you can change the `toolkit:` namespace into the one dedicated to WP8 controls to use the "official" and supported control.

Hope it will make you save some time

Comment: I'm actually gonna write it myself, since virtualization is provided out-of-the-box, so it's not a concern, plus I need a WP8 `MultiLongListSelector` for multiple Contacts selection and the search functionality which this Control lacks. But hey, this is all the fun about it! Thanks though, the link you provided is the perfect place to start.

Comment: You're welcome, Happy coding with your own contact chooser ;)